# But by and large

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, phrase-meaning

I came across a sentence that started like this:

> but by and large, groups of words without a verb are like a car without an engine — they can’t go anywhere.

It was hard for me to conjure up context for what I was reading at that moment. What does “but by and large” mean?

Comment: What **was** the context? *But* signals that what follows contrasts with what precedes it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @StoneyB what followed after the the phrase is the context.

Comment: It's an idiom.  [Definition of "by and large"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by%20and%20large), meaning "on the whole" or "in general" or "for the most part" or various similar idioms.  Try using google to look up idiomatic phrases -- if they are valid, they should show up in one or more dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**By and large**" roughly means *generally* or *on the whole*. So in this context, your sentence would read:

> but generally, groups of words without a verb are like a car
>   without an engine — they can’t go anywhere.